# HTML5 cache and authorization issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, authentication, caching, backbone.js

I've got a problem after adding HTML5 caching to a singlepage app written in backbone on rails. Browser (chrome) isn't reloading the html and this causes problems in 2 ways:

1) The skeleton html for backbone sometimes changes - at very least to let backbone know that user is signed in. However with html not being loaded, the app doesn't know that (after refresh for example). I could query the server on page load, but that's another request which I hopped to avoid. Also this would force moving all the permisions logic to the client - so either duplicate cancan setting from the server OR embed it in html - and we run into above issue.

2) Rails' csrf tokens are in the html, and they too don't change - causing any ajax post to not work. For this one I'm not sure what to do. From what I read csrf token is generated for session so maybe on login/logout I could update it with js. However where to get it, would it work ?

Comment: The page which references the manifest is always included in the appcache.  You should load *all* non-static data with JavaScript, or you need to update the manifest file every time your HTML changes.

Answer (score 0):

i know this question is old but i just ran into the CSRF issue.

Try including the CSRF token as a comment in the manifest file. So whenever it changes it will change the manifest and force a reload.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# include CSRF token in manifest to force reload when it changes
# <%= form_authenticity_token %>
```

to be safe you could run it through a hashing algorithm a few times