# HTML5 Application Cache and CSRF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, caching

I'm building an Rails web application that will be saved to the iOS home screen. When an app is saved to the home screen, iOS refuses to cache images. To get around this, I decided to give HTML5's application caching a try.

I set up my manifest file and the caching works beautifully. However, when the CSRF token expires, I'm unable to get a new one because the HTML page is implicitly included with the manifest. **How can I get CSRF working with HTML5's application caching?**

Comment: This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693626/html5-cache-and-authorization-issues. It  suggests adding CSRF token as a comment in manifest. And that    will  force a reload when CSRF token expire.

Comment: Are there any security implications of doing that? The site recommended running it through a hash, but is that enough?

Comment: I don't think this will add any extra security issues. But there is a general vulnerability related  to csrf for offline apps.(http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/demystifying-html-5-attacks/).